# how can I remove \" from json in SQL or c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, json

I want to save JSON to SQL Server and can read it as a text without \r\n and \"

Code of saving to DataBase:

```
JObject data=...
objTableA.fieldA= data.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

with this code, when I read **objTableA.fieldA** it gives me without \r\n, but the problem is , I can see **\"** in my result

So how can I solve it

good result:

```
{"userId":"75","IsComment":"true","IsCommentReply":"true","IsLikes":"true","IsFollow":"true","IsCommercial":"true","IsMention":"true","IsNewMember":"true"}
```

wrong result:

```
{\"userId\":\"75\",\"IsComment\":\"true\",\"IsCommentReply\":\"true\",\"IsLikes\":\"true\",\"IsFollow\":\"true\",\"IsCommercial\":\"true\",\"IsMention\":\"true\",\"IsNewMember\":\"true\"}
```

Comment: A sample of the JSON data would be useful

Comment: Where should I find this sample :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert a string to json object.

try this

```
var data = "{\"userId\":\"75\",\"IsComment\":\"true\",\"IsCommentReply\":\"true\",\"IsLikes\":\"true\",\"IsFollow\":\"true\",\"IsCommercial\":\"true\",\"IsMention\":\"true\",\"IsNewMember\":\"true\"}";

JObject parseData = JObject.Parse(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want :)